# how to add custom configuration e.g. host_name = "www.abc.com" in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

how to add custom configuration e.g. host_name = "www.abc.com" in symfony2 ? I know we can access the hostname using request object but I want the host name in symfony CLI custom command.

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code, and be more specific (read the help section for this site to see what makes a good question)

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html, solved my problem.

Comment: here, http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html, it is suggested to add custom config to parameters.yml, it is neccessary to use parameters.yml or any other config file would work ? parameter.yml has database settings which are different for local. staging, production, so I have added it to .gitignore file.

Comment: then you should use a parameters.yml.dist file, were every developer copies it's parameters.yml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html

```
parameters:
    router.request_context.host: example.org
    router.request_context.scheme: https
    router.request_context.base_url: my/path

$context = $this->getContainer()->get('router')->getContext();
```

worked.